# Protractor File upload failing with ng upload version 3.3.4

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing

I have been using the usual file upload in the protractor to upload the files .

```
element(by.id('upload_button')).sendKeys('file path');
```

It was working fine until our application's `ng upload` upgraded to `version 3.3.4`.

We are using protractor Version `1.4.0`.

Is this a known issue ?? Does anyone know a workaround for this

Comment: How does it currently fail? Please provide a stack trace.

Comment: UnknownError: unknown error: [ng:test] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/ng/test
(Session info: chrome=42.0.2311.135)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.12.301326 (093c7e07b4a916b690e784b0374c7f618f1ea4be),platform=Mac OS X 10.9.5 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: @alecxe dint get any stack trace